# Is there an alternative way to add up multiple closes in Pine v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Basically creating a custom indicator and need the previous indicator value added up. I’m currently using the following code:

`exampleName = exCloseVal + exCloseVal[1] + exCloseVal[2] +  exCloseVal[3] + exCloseVal[4] + exCloseVal[5]`

Now let’s say I wanted the past 100 bar close values added up, would there be an alternative way to add them up, rather than typing it out the way I am up to 100?

Many thanks for reading and would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `math.sum` for that.

```
math.sum(source, length) → series float
```

> The sum function returns the sliding sum of last y values of x.
>
> **RETURNS**
> Sum of `source` for `length` bars back.\
>
> **ARGUMENTS**
> ***source (series int/float)*** Series of values to process.
> ***length (series int)*** Number of bars (length).

```
exCloseVal_sum = math.sum(exCloseVal, 100)
```